# Any apps or ways to categories group apps folders in menu view

Tags: applications, launcher, app-drawer, application-manager, folder-organizer

Question :- Any apps or ways to categories group apps folders in menu view

Is there any apps or  setting to categories group move apps installed icons in folders inside menu view.  as there is jumble of apps to search in alphabetical order which cant be moved or.clubed inside menu view of. Android 6.0 unrooted mobile phone.

I had searched Google and.finded smart launcher go launcher x or drawer to. Circle launchers but all just change wallpapers or screens or  create widgets folder organizer manager but no one manages the menu view

Yes I know we can create folder in home (mobile desktop views) but rereating folders shortcut making home screens desktop jumbled will slow down booting of  Android starting and many time it don't display icon image on reboot of mobiles.

Can we create self menu (as start menu in Windows properly organised) through app and hide the original menu and replace our own menu. I have seen a circle.menu recreated by some apps.

Any stable good idea or  app to create organize categorise apps icons shortcuts in a menu view as it's not customisable in Android 6.

Comment: Sorry but I understand may be 20% of your question because of the language you use (what ever it is).

Comment: @Robert bro sorry it was due to auto correct I tried best to elaborate correct and make it understand you cAn suggest edits to